# Universal cubic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory

A universal quadratic form is a positive definite quadratic form, which represents every positive integer. E. g., by Lagrange's four-square theorem, the form $\ x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ is universal, and Ramanujan found the other ones.
But is there some universal cubic form, which represents all integers (if it represents all positive integers, it represents the negative ones as well). Certainly $\ x_1^3+x_2^3+...+x_9^3$ is a universal cubic form, because the solution of Waring's problem for 3 is 9. Is there a classification, similar to Ramanujan's, of universal cubic forms?

Comment: I think the question should be put differently. What form with minimal number of summands can be. To determine all the numbers.

Comment: For what it's worth, this question is likely to be a lot harder than the corresponding case of quadratic forms. For example, we don't even know if $33$ is represented by $x_{1}^{3} + x_{2}^{3} + x_{3}^{3}$.

Comment: If you allow cubes of negative integers, then $v^{3}+w^{3}+x^{3}+y^{3}+z^{3}$ does represent all integers. Further, there is a preprint by Samir Siksek in the arXiv in which he proves this: every $n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{15, 22, 23, 50, 114, 167, 175, 186, 212, 231, 238, 239, 303, 364, 420, 428, 454\}$ can be written as the sum of at most seven non-negative perfect cubes.

Comment: If negative integers are allowed then $(x+1)^3+2(-x)^3+(x-1)^3$ represents all multiples of 6 and so $x^3+2y^3+z^3+w^3$ represents all integers.

Comment: @Jeremy Rouse Now we do.